# Differences in Maven builds between local (Windows / IntelliJ) and remote (Linux)?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jax-rs, swagger

I'm seeing something odd where I'm doing a Maven build that is implementing the swagger doclet for our API documentation (https://github.com/ryankennedy/swagger-jaxrs-doclet). When I do the build as reccommended there on the github page it builds fine locally on my Windows machine. The strangeness occurs when I try to do the exact same build on my Lunix vm and I get an error about unparsable POM files. A big difference I'm noticing is on the local machine there's a jar being pulled in that doesn't exist on the linux box: jaxrs-doclet-parent. This I'm assuming has something to do with the unparseable pom file error on the vm. Does anyone have an idea why a build would execute successfully on Windows (built via IntelliJ) but not on Linux?

Maven version is 3.0.3 on linux box and version is 3.2.1 on local windows machine

Here's the build error I am referring to:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 37.339s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jul 24 12:38:36 EDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 32M/76M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9.1:javadoc (generate-service-docs) on project scapi-ws: An error has occurred in JavaDocs report generation: Unable to build the Maven project for the artifact:groupId = 'com.hypnoticocelot'
[ERROR] artifactId = 'jaxrs-doclet'
[ERROR] version = '0.0.4-SNAPSHOT': 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model
[ERROR] [FATAL] Non-parseable POM /home/gwalker/.m2/repository/com/hypnoticocelot/jaxrs-doclet/0.0.4-SNAPSHOT/jaxrs-doclet-0.0.4-SNAPSHOT.pom: end tag name </body> must match start tag name <hr> from line 5 (position: TEXT seen ...</center>\r\n</body>... @6:8)  @ line 6, column 8
```

Comment: Could you add some info please? Namely the (unparsable?) Part of the pom, maven version, the exact error ?

Comment: The first thing I'd look at is your maven settings.xml files.  Is there a difference between your local maven settings file and the one in your Linux VM?  Perhaps you've configured the repositories differently?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the maven version. On the linux box it was 3.0.3 and needed to be upgraded. Once I upgraded to 3.2.1 it built ok.