# Maven Build Result Differs between Windows and Unix Machines

Tags: java, windows, maven, unix, build

I have a maven project; I build it using maven 3.5.0 with following options:

```
clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -X
```

I executed maven build in three different machines:

1. Debian Jessie 8.5
2. Ubuntu 16.04
3. Windows 10

I use maven 3.5.0 on all of them, but the only machine which its output is doing as expected, is the Windows one. Maven settings are identical.

I used a JAR comparison tool in order to find differences; there was just some ignorable changes.

To be completely clear and in case this information may be useful to suggest a solution, I think I should explain what is wrong with unix machines maven output.

The maven project provides a REST API. In unix machines, the server adds a DOS character at the end of each line of request.

This is log of the server which is built on Unix machines:

```
Received [GET /auth-server/v2/api/me HTTP/1.1^M
Authorization: Bearer 8631dff0-323a-4058-a55e-505dc65f5f4c^M
cache-control: no-cache^M
Postman-Token: f71d256e-4036-4201-889a-36e3782c7bf2^M
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.1.1^M
Accept: */*^M
Host: 192.168.100.185:1998^M
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate^M
Connection: keep-alive^M
^M
]
```

This is log of the server is built on windows machine:

```
Received [GET /auth-server/v2/api/me HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer 8631dff0-323a-4058-a55e-505dc65f5f4c
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: f71d256e-4036-4201-889a-36e3782c7bf2
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.1.1
Accept: */*
Host: 192.168.100.185:1998
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive

]
```

As you see, the `^M` character at the end of the line containing `Authorization` field changes its value; this makes the header values invalid in server side.

I did not expect server to add those `^M` characters at the end of request lines.

Is there anything different between machines about java? Isn't java a cross-platform language?

If it helps, I should mention that the development was done on a Windows machine.

After some googling, I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937585/differences-in-maven-builds-between-local-windows-intellij-and-remote-linux) which is not useful in my case.

Comment: I did not understand what expected behaviour fails when you use Linux.

Comment: @JFMeier, I did not expect server to add those `^M` characters at the end of request lines.

Comment: `^M` means `\r : carriage-return` character and expected at there. What tool did you use to parse http headers?

Comment: see https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2.2

Comment: @TaherKhorshidi, server doesn't accept `^M` and authentication fails. No tool is taking part there; a request from the exact same client is being send to server and the server parses the request. In windows case, no `^M` character is added; since the client and the request don't change, it seems the server functions differently.

Comment: the maven project is `client` or `server` ?

Comment: @TaherKhorshidi, the maven project is the server.